# PHP Looping binary xor

Tags: php

how to looping key as long $text this is my code :

```
function _xor($text,$key){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){
        $text[$i] = intval($text[$i])^intval($key[$i]);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

result of the above code does not repeat as much as `$key` length `$text`.
I want as much as `$key` in `$text` and re-XORed
how to repeat?

Comment: Can you show an actual example of what the expected result  and actual result are?

Comment: Do you mean what your key is smaller than text?

Comment: Just as a side note, try to use `strlen()` outside the loop: `$size = strlen($str); for($i = 0; $i < $size; ...) { ... }` no use calculating the size every loop. :)

Comment: ahh true what you say @VitalyS.

Comment: @Esailija this is example $text = 0110000101100001 and long 16 the $key = 01100001 and long 8 I want as much as $key in $text and re-XORed how to repeat

Answer (score 1):

You have to use modulo operator to work only with [0 .. strlen($key)-1] indexes of $key string.
If you put `$i % strlen($key)` you'll get values from zero to strlen($key) - 1 in loop

```php
function _xor($text,$key){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($text); $i++){
        $text[$i] = intval($text[$i])^intval($key[$i % strlen($key)]);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

PS: Information about modulo operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, instead of a code dump.  What's the % doing etc.  Thanks.